# Turn on compiler optimization for Android Studio debug build via Cmake

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, cmake

I am using Android Studio 3.0 for my NDK based app.
For the C++ code, I use [CMake as the external builder](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-cmake-script).

This works well, I can create debug and release binaries.

However, I would like to turn on compiler optimizations (say -O3) for a part of the C++ code (the physics engine),  not just for the release build, but also for the debug build.

So create the bulk of the debug build as is, without optimizing, yet, I want one of the static library targets to be built with the compiler optimization enabled.

How can I go about this?

I have a CMakeLists for a static library target that gets included using [add_subdirectory()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) directive in the top level CMakeLists file.

Note that I point to the top level CMakeLists in my app's build.gradle file like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path '../../Android/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that you can use the [target_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html) macro in your CMakeLists.txt with a config specification like this:

```
target_compile_options(opende PRIVATE
"$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
"$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O3>"
)
```

This macro adds to the existing compile options.